# CSS: Force same width for two columns of a three-column table

Tags: html, css, width, tabular

Given a three-column table, I want the first two columns to always have the same dynamic width -- that is, as small as possible, but the two columns need to always share width. The third column should fill the rest of the available container width.

Example:

```
+----+----+--------------+
|  A |  B |      C       |
+----+----+--------------+
|1234|  12|           foo|
+----+----+--------------+
|   a|   b|           bar|
+----+----+--------------+
```

Note that B is 4 chars wide although its content fits into a 2-char column.

Hardcoding the width of column A and B isn't a solution because the content varies in size.

Comment: Some code youve tried would be nice

Comment: Any update regarding this question? Is it possible to solve with flexbox or grids?

Answer (score 0):

will force the first two columns to be small as possible
http://jsfiddle.net/DYeyp/

```
​<table border=1 style='width:100%;'>
​<tr>
 ​   <td style='width:1%;'>1111</td>
  ​  <td style='width:1%;'>1111</td>
  ​  <td>1</td>
​</tr>
​<tr>
 ​   <td>1</td>
  ​  <td>1</td>
  ​  <td>1</td>
​</tr>
​<tr>
 ​   <td>1</td>
  ​  <td>1</td>
  ​  <td>1</td>
​</tr>
​</table>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: This only works if the width of the content does exceed the width of the percentage defined.

Comment: what? theres no way for it to not exceed 1% width

Comment: Take a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zJBRr/ they are the same width only if the content is the same width.

Comment: oh both columns have to be the same width ok, one sec

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible only with css, its probably possible with javascript, but that's never a good option. There is a way to do this, its not very beautiful, but it might work: if you are using php to feed the table with data you could make a invisible div in the second row that has the exact same data as the first row. For example:

```
<div class="NoSelect" style="display: inline-block; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;">
--echo here the same data as in the first row--
</div>
```

And to make the text inside unselectable you could add:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .NoSelect {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: default;
    }
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.fn.extend({ 
        disableSelection : function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                this.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
                this.unselectable = 'on';
            });
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.NoSelect').disableSelection();
    }
</script>
```